# Nginx - прокси в пределах одного сайта

Tags: nginx, proxy, config

По сути, мне нужно, чтобы при запросе `https://example.com/news` показывалась `https://example.com/pages/?id=21` без изменения адреса в строке браузера. Сайт на https, все в пределах одного домена. Да, я знаю, что это плохая практика.

Я пробовал гуглить в сторону proxy_pass, но там примеры, связанные с запросом других сайтов/серверов и у меня они не работают.

Answer (score 1):

```
server {
    ....
    rewrite ^/listings/(.*)$ /listing.html?listing=$1 last;
    ....
}
```

Переписывает  http://mysite.com/listings/123 на http://mysite.com/listing.html?listing=123.

Comment: К сожалению, в итоге я получаю ошибку 404. Пробовал даже переписывать на / (т.е. главную страницу сайта). Может ли rewrite быть отключен?